# SQL - Count Number of Records with Combined Sum

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a User table similar to this:

```
|  ID  |  DONATION  |   RANK   |
|  4   |        10  |     12   |
|  9   |        20  |      8   |
|  2   |        40  |      5   |
|  3   |        80  |      2   |
```

I would like to construct a query where I retrieve the number of users where the combined sum of the donations is less than say 100, ordered by rank... something like (obviously not correct):

```
select count(*) where sum(donation) < 100 order by rank
```

Can't figure out how to do this if it's even possible. Not even sure I'm going about this the right way. Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: The goal here is not clear. The problem is `the combined sum of the donations` which means you have to group your users in a certain way. Like USER 4 and 3 is a group with 90 total donation, USER 4,9 and 2 can also be grouped with a total of 70. Is rank a determining factor in creating your groups?

Comment: i think he might mean 'combined sum of the donations' on a per donater basis (i.e. based on the ID)  ?  Then just do a group by / having clause methinks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the following Donation table (as much as I think your ID column points to a user, I could not be sure):

```
| ID | UserId | Donation |
| 1  | 1      | 60       |
| 2  | 1      | 35       |
| 3  | 2      | 70       |
| 4  | 2      | 40       |
| 5  | 3      | 90       |
```

The the following query will give you the number of users with their total donation < 100

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT  UserId
    FROM    Donations 
    GROUP BY UserId
    HAVING SUM(Donation) < 100
) AS t
```

---

Update based on extra information.
I do not believe you can get what you want from a single SQL statement, what you would need to do is create a cursor that loops around the records you want (in appropiate order) inserting the id into a temp table, and maintaining a total of the donations.  When the total is above your limit, break out of the cursor loop and return the results.  Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTopDontations( limit DECIMAL(...) )
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (
        id INT
    );

    DECLARE total, Donation DECIMAL(...);
    DECLARE Id INT;
    DECLARE curDonations CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, Dontaion FROM Donations ORDER BY <something relevant>;

    SET total = 0.0;
    OPEN curDonations;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH curDonations INTO Id, Donation;
        INSERT INTO t1( id ) VALUES ( Id );
        SET total = total + Donation;
        IF( total > limit ) THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP:
    CLOSE curDonations;

    SELECT d.*
    FROM    Donations d
        INNER JOIN t1
            ON d.Id = t1.Id;
END;
```

Comment: This is close, but there is only a single record per user. I'm essentially trying to grab some quick stats... ordered by rank, looking for the first subset (read count) of users who make up the first $100 in donations, etc.

Comment: You will probably not get that in one SQL statement, you could however use a cursor, while the total of Donation is < 100, put the id into a temporary table, then just select all the donations that are in the temp table.

Answer (score 6):

WHERE only works for columns or expressions, if you want to filter with an aggregate function (like SUM), you have to use HAVING. For example :

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM your_table
  HAVING SUM(donation) < 100
```

This query doesn't really make sense without a valid GROUP BY, but you get the point: use HAVING to filter with an aggregate function. Technically, you should group by user id then do the count, and sum the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, sum(donation) AS totalDonation 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY id
HAVING totalDonation < 100
```